# How to create an account when and assign it to a User when signing up via Clearance in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, user-accounts, clearance

What is the best way with Clearance to automatically create a an "Account" with a unique account_id (doesn't have to be UUID) and assign it to the new user on sign up?

I need to extend the clearance User sign up form and User controller to handle this but I'm having trouble getting this to work.

Should this be a before_filter on signup or part of the User create action?

---

Update: Adding some code for reference...

```
# app/controllers/users_controller.rb
class UsersController < Clearance::UsersController

  def create
    @user = user_from_params
    @account = account_from_params
    @user.account = @account

    if @user.save
      sign_in @user
      redirect_back_or url_after_create
    else
      render template: "users/new"
    end
  end

end

class AccountController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @account = Account.new(account_params)
  end

  private

  def account_params
    params[:account].permit(:id)
  end

end

<fieldset>
  <%= form.label :email %>
  <%= form.text_field :email, type: 'email' %>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
  <%= form.label :password %>
  <%= form.password_field :password %>
</fieldset>


# Users & Clearance routes
  resources :passwords, controller: 'clearance/passwords', only: [:create, :new]
  resource :session, controller: 'clearance/sessions', only: [:create]

  resources :users, controller: 'clearance/users', only: [:create] do
    resource :password,
      controller: 'clearance/passwords',
      only: [:create, :edit, :update]
  end
  get '/login' => 'clearance/sessions#new', as: 'sign_in'
  delete '/logout' => 'clearance/sessions#destroy', as: 'sign_out'
  get '/signup' => 'clearance/users#new', as: 'sign_up'
  get '/users' => 'users#index'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would hook into their controllers to keep things "in the gem" so to speak. [This is how it works](https://github.com/thoughtbot/clearance#controllers). Looks like you would hook into the controllers by overriding them like this:

```
class UsersController < Clearance::UsersController

  def create
    @user = user_from_params
    @account = account_from_params
    @user.account = @account

    if @user.save
      sign_in @user
      redirect_back_or url_after_create
    else
      render template: "users/new"
    end
  end

end
```

Don't forget to update the routes and point them to this controller action. Now, you're sort of unhooking your controller `create` action from Clearance, but you're doing it in a "Clearance way" which seems most appropriate.

Comment: Thanks. This seems like the right approach and is definitely pointing me in the right direction. Still having trouble getting the form to work. I noticed 'user_from_params` in the Clearance User controller, but where should `account_from_params` be coming from? Is this some rails magic? Do I need to add an account_id hidden field to the form?

Comment: Eh, I'm not super familiar with Clearance, but you don't need to use their syntax. You should just pass any necessary params to the controller and grab it Rails-style. Either `@account = Account.find(params[:account_id])` from a hidden_field like you said or (if it's also created) `@account = Account.new(account_params)` where you need to define a private `account_params` method that gets the account details from the params.

Comment: So one way to do this would be to add the "Name" field to the user sign up form as a nested attributes, but because my Account model `has_many :users` and my User model `has_many :users` and `accepts_nested_attributes_for :users`, but that form is not working either. Is this totally the wrong approach? Is there a way to do the opposite of this in a rails form? I need Users to belong to the account so that it leaves the option for multiple users to be a part of the same account as a part of a team that can access the account.

Comment: Here's what I'm trying to do with my accounts/new form https://gist.github.com/leemcalilly/83a9ff2248c35b3e7c498466bb2829e7