# Modeling a multi-tenant rails app so that it's easy to maintain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, architecture, data-modeling, multi-tenant, clearance

I'm building a multi-tenant rails app that is using a shared database where data is siloed by scoping everything to each account (similar to [Basecamp 3](https://basecamp.com))—rather than with separate tables and subdomains. The approach I'm taking is described [here](http://andrewmarkle.com/2016/04/06/multitenancy-with-pundit/).

Each account will have its own data (e.g. products, inventory), and many users with different roles (e.g. account owner, employee, customer, etc.). I'm using [Clearance](https://github.com/thoughtbot/clearance) for User signup and login.

It seems like there are two approaches that I could take with modeling an app like this:

1. An account owner signs up and creates their account sorta like creating a profile. I'd create the account via nested fields on the sign up form. Everything inherits from the Account owner like this...
   [image]

---

2. Or, when a new user signs up a new Account is created and associated with that User (should this happen with a callback?). Everything (such as products and other users like employees or customers) inherit from the account, not the account owner. The account owner is just another User that belongs to the Account.
   [image]

It seems like option 2 is the simpler solution, but I'm blocked on how to create the Account when a new user signs up via Clearance. I've gone into [more detail on this problem here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55380556/how-to-create-an-account-when-and-assign-it-to-a-user-when-signing-up-via-cleara/55381977?noredirect=1#comment97527225_55381977), but I'm worried that the way I'm modeling my app with Option 2 is not ideal.

Which one of these approaches is going to be simplest to setup and maintain? Or, is there another way to model this that I'm missing?

Because I'd eventually like the site to have some users that are customers, should I take [the approach](https://leanpub.com/multi-tenancy-rails) of using Subdomains (like Shopify?).

Comment: In both models you end up with the same tables right? Even in option 2, I'd still create a scoped has_one relation to User table that I would name :account_owner, so I don't  really see the difference between the two suggested models. I think even when choosing one of the two, it wouldn't be too much of an effort to switch, or am I missing some trivial part?

Comment: Yes it would be the same tables. I guess I'm struggling to figure out the best way to associate them and work it into the sign up form. For instance, should the Account belong to the User? In that scenario if they come through the sign up form the account could be created with a callback and if they are sent an invite then their account is assigned. Or, should the User belong to the account? In that case, how is the Account created when a new user signs up?

Comment: I think it Also depends on whether the Account Owner shares a lot of logic with the other types of Users. Will Customers / Employees also be able to login (like a user does). Will you eventually allow shared ownership of the Account with multiple Account owners, etc. you could even consider a Role table in between Account and map the type of role each user plays with a specific Account.

Comment: Yeah the Account Owner will share a lot of logic with the other users. Looks like my "Option 2" is the approach this book takes https://leanpub.com/multi-tenancy-rails-2/read_sample

Answer (score 0):

So, I'm not sure how well this solution will work as the app evolves over time, but I ended up going with this flow for now if it helps anyone else with a similar problem:

1. User signs up via clearance sign up form at /signup
2. After signing up they are redirected to accounts/new if they have not created an account
3. Accounts `belong_to` User and every User `has_one` Account
4. Everything else, like Products, `belong_to` the Account
5. User roles are set based on how you sign up. So if you sign up from the homepage you are the Account Owner by default.
6. Access control is determined by User roles and Pundit.
7. Data is siloed because everything else, like products, `belong_to` the Account

Here's a sketch of the relationships:
[image]

Here's the code:

accounts_controller.rb

```
# POST /accounts
  def create
    @user    = current_user
    @account = @user.build_account(account_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @account.save
        format.html { redirect_to @account, notice: 'Account was successfully created.' }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
      end
    end
  end


  def account_params
    params.require(:account).permit(:company_name, :user_id)
  end
```

models/account.rb

```
class Account < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end
```

models/user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  include Clearance::User
  has_one :account
end
```